# How can I add one random number to an array in React setState hook while in StrictMode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm writing some React code and I'd like to add a push a random number to the end of an `items` array on the click of a button.

I'm running React in StrictMode and I'm aware that this is causing my setState hooks to run twice which is causing two random numbers to be added to my array rather than just one.

My question is: what is the best way to get around this? My code is below.

```js
const { useState, StrictMode } = React;

function App() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ul>
                {items.map((item, index)=><li key={index}>Item {item}</li>)}
            </ul>

            <button onClick={() => setItems(prevItems => {
                let newItem = Math.random()
                prevItems.push(newItem)
                return [...prevItems]
                }
            )}>Add Item</button>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <StrictMode>
        <App />
    </StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The good news is that `StrictMode` did exactly what it was supposed to do: It flagged up an error in the code. :-)

The problem is that you're breaking one of the rules of React state: You're modifying `prevItems` directly (via `.push`). That means if your `setState` callback function is called twice, even though it gets passed the same `prevItems` array both times, because you **modified** that array, you end up with two entries.

It's like doing this:

```js
const setItems = prevItems => {
    let newItem = Math.random();
    prevItems.push(newItem);
    return [...prevItems];
};

const items = [1];
let newItems;
newItems = setItems(items);
newItems = setItems(items); // Randomly introduced by StrictMode

console.log(newItems);
```

If you fix it, you won't get duplication:

```
setItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, Math.random()]);
```

Which is like this:

```js
const setItems = prevItems => [...prevItems, Math.random()];

const items = [1];
let newItems;
newItems = setItems(items);
newItems = setItems(items); // Randomly introduced by StrictMode

console.log(newItems);
```

Here's your snippet with the change:

```js
const { useState, StrictMode } = React;

function App() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ul>
                {items.map((item, index)=><li key={index}>Item {item}</li>)}
            </ul>

            <button onClick={
                () => setItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, Math.random()])
            }>Add Item</button>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <StrictMode>
        <App />
    </StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

As you can see, clicking `Add Item` only ever adds one.